# chef knife commands show missing extensions on OSX El Capitan 10.11

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra, knife

every time I run a `knife` command, I'm getting a large list of extensions not found.  but when I try to install them nothing works.

```
$ knife ssh 'name:foo.bar.baz' 'php -v' -a ipaddress 

Ignoring dep-selector-libgecode-1.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine dep-selector-libgecode --version 1.0.2
Ignoring eventmachine-1.0.8 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine eventmachine --version 1.0.8
Ignoring eventmachine-1.0.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine eventmachine --version 1.0.7
Ignoring ffi-yajl-2.2.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi-yajl --version 2.2.2
Ignoring gherkin-2.12.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gherkin --version 2.12.2
Ignoring hitimes-1.2.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine hitimes --version 1.2.3
Ignoring http_parser.rb-0.6.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine http_parser.rb --version 0.6.0
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring msgpack-0.5.12 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine msgpack --version 0.5.12
Ignoring nio4r-1.1.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nio4r --version 1.1.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring puma-1.6.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine puma --version 1.6.3
Ignoring ruby-shadow-2.4.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ruby-shadow --version 2.4.1
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.1
172.18.4.218 PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.12 (cli) (built: Aug 13 2015 22:34:42) 
172.18.4.218 Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
172.18.4.218 Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
172.18.4.218     with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v5.0.18, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by ionCube Ltd.
172.18.4.218     with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

yet - if I try to take one of the suggestions it fails

```
$ gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Failed to find gems ["nokogiri"] = 1.6.6.2
```

I tried installing nokogiri and other extension w/out specifying the version and that works, but doesn't resolve any issues when I run the commands aftwards.

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (default: 1.2.8)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
eventmachine (1.2.0.1)
io-console (default: 0.4.5)
json (default: 1.8.3)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
minitest (5.8.3)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nokogiri (1.6.8)
pkg-config (1.1.7)
power_assert (0.2.6)
psych (default: 2.0.17)
puma (3.5.2)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (default: 4.2.1)
rubygems-update (2.6.6)
test-unit (3.1.5)
```

Comment: We recommend you install Chef on your workstation using the ChefDK installers, which include their own Ruby environment and a known safe gem collection.

Comment: I did utilize the chefdk installers, but I still seem to be getting these errors.  `$ ls -l $(which knife) 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    21B Jul 22 15:57 /usr/local/bin/knife@ -> /opt/chefdk/bin/knife`

Comment: NM, looks like my system ruby was not set to the chefdk ruby - once I updated that - it fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was resolved by using the ChefDK Ruby instead of a system-default Ruby.

Comment: Please expand! What can I type to fix the same error?

Comment: The specifics depend on your current set up, but mostly just install ChefDK and don't monkey with it.

Comment: What is ChefDK?